# Google App Engine block unauthorized urls

Tags: security, google-app-engine

I recently started using Google App engine for hosting a Node.js application. The app is still in development and thus should be dormant most of the time, but I noticed that I am getting a lot of activity each day, which results in Google billing me for 'up time'. Inspecting the logs I see that I am getting loads of 'url scans' to no existent url's

```
A  404 18 B 1 ms GET Chrome 56 / 404 18 B 1 ms GET Chrome 56 
A  404 18 B 2 ms GET Chrome 56 /portal/client/cms/viewcmspage.action 404 18 B 2 ms GET Chrome 56 
A  404 18 B 1 ms GET Chrome 56 /admin/agent/default.action 404 18 B 1 ms GET Chrome 56 
A  404 18 B 1 ms GET Chrome 56 /vportal/web/gateway/home.action 404 18 B 1 ms GET Chrome 56 
A  404 18 B 1 ms GET Chrome 56 /struts2_2.3.15.1-showcase/showcase.action 404 18 B 1 ms GET Chrome 56 
A  404 18 B 1 ms GET Chrome 56 /struts2-showcase/login.action 404 18 B 1 ms GET Chrome 56 
A  404 18 B 1 ms GET Chrome 56 /struts/login.action 404 18 B 1 ms GET Chrome 56 
A  404 18 B 1 ms GET Chrome 56 /struts2/login.action 404 18 B 1 ms GET Chrome 56 
A  404 18 B 1 ms GET Chrome 56 /web/Index.action 404 18 B 1 ms GET Chrome 56 
A  404 18 B 1 ms GET - /phpmyadmin/scripts/setup.php 404 18 B 1 ms GET - 
A  404 18 B 1 ms GET Chrome 56 / 404 18 B 1 ms GET Chrome 56 
A  404 18 B 2 ms GET Chrome 56 /portal/client/cms/viewcmspage.action 404 18 B 2 ms GET Chrome 56 
A  404 18 B 1 ms GET Chrome 56 /admin/agent/default.action 404 18 B 1 ms GET Chrome 56 
A  404 18 B 1 ms GET Chrome 56 /vportal/web/gateway/home.action 404 18 B 1 ms GET Chrome 56 
A  404 18 B 1 ms GET Chrome 56 /struts2_2.3.15.1-showcase/showcase.action 404 18 B 1 ms GET Chrome 56 
A  404 18 B 1 ms GET Chrome 56 /struts2-showcase/login.action 404 18 B 1 ms GET Chrome 56 
A  404 18 B 1 ms GET Chrome 56 /struts/login.action 404 18 B 1 ms GET Chrome 56 
A  404 18 B 1 ms GET Chrome 56 /struts2/login.action 404 18 B 1 ms GET Chrome 56 
A  404 18 B 2 ms GET Chrome 56 /web/Index.action 404 18 B 2 ms GET Chrome 56 
A  404 18 B 1 ms GET the beast /phpmyadmin/scripts/setup.php 404 18 B 1 ms GET the beast
```

Is there any way for me to block these, or change the port my app runs on? I tried using the firewall, but from what I see it only applies to "Compute engine".

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work: during development, enable the Identity Aware Proxy in front of your app to block any users except yourself or other developers that you authorize. The Identity Aware Proxy allows you to specify Google accounts (Gmail, G Suite domains, etc) that are allowed to access your application. Because this occurs before they connect with your account I believe it should stop random traffic from messing with your billing.

1. Navigate to the [Identity Aware Proxy page](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/gatekeeper/project) in the Google Cloud Platform Console.
2. Enable the IAP toggle.
3. Enter the appspot.com or custom domains URLs that you want to enforce the login restrictions in front of.
4. In the Access pane, click **Add** and enter your Gmail or Google account email address.
5. Verify that only your signed in account can hit your URLs test an incognito connection to see verify it does not hit your URL prior to the proxy.

Comment: I did look into this, but the problem is that the node.js is a REST api for mobile app's. I could use this during development as I have limited testers, but this will not be ideal in prod.

Comment: Given that we're talking about the flexible environment there is not a scale to zero functionality so you're always running and paying for at least one instance. I wouldn't think you'd get enough garbage requests that likely 404 that would increase your load enough to go beyond that single instance.

You can disable your app in the App Engine Settings area of the console when you aren't actively using it, that would definitely save on costs and won't result in instance spin up.